# Does setting your name to 00000 make you gray?

Tags: among-us

If your username is 00000, the secret gray crewmate's name, will your color become gray, or will nothing happen at all?

Comment: One question at a time please, and be honest, are you really expecting answers for this *question*?

Comment: It's more likely that 0 is the secret crew member's internal id, not name.

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5498/258509

Comment: AFAIK, the Among Us files don't even have a gray character sprite.

Comment: Fun fact, you didn't look for crewmate #11 bro! Crewmate #11 is the gray crewmate's crewmate#

Comment: @OKprogrammer The sprites in Among Us are all colour-independent, I believe. They have red, green and blue which get replaced by the colour at runtime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of v2021.4.14s:

No. You will still remain in your own styling when loaded into a game.

Proof [here](https://youtu.be/haisZvtjT-s).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is no. I don't think it is possible for your color to become gray just by the username.

Comment: Another alternative is that there is a reasonable chance that the Among Us servers can deny the username.

Comment: It could be like one of those Minecraft name tags things, but why didn't OP just hop on Among Us and try it, when its this simple?